# Syntax Error INSERT INTO Statement Access DB

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Not sure if this specific error has been found, but I cannot see where I have my syntax incorrect with this `INSERT INTO` statement:

I have split it up into Insert and Values for easier reading. This is a string that is created by VBA and then passed to the connection.

The specific error I'm getting is -2147217900 (8004e14)
"Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement"

```
INSERT INTO AS_Processing_2_2 (ImportDate, [Month], [Year], [Plant Name], [Plant Number], PDFReference, a_VAR_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, a1_BPMH_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, a2_EFF_ON_44FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, a3_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH_RANK, a4_WB_BPMH_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, b_BPMH_BY_DEPT_REC_WOG_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, b1_KILL_BPMH_BY_DEPT_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, b2_EVISWOG_BPMH_BY_DEPT_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, b3_WB_EVIS_BPMH_BY_DEPT_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, c_PRCT_LINE_EFFCY_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, d_VAR_GIB_HARV_EFFCY_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, d1_LIVGIZ_HIS_LB_MH_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, d2_LABORperLB_C__FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, d3_STAFF_per_LINE_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, e_TOTAL_GIB_RECVR_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, e1_LIVER_25_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, e2_GIZ_HT_22_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, f_NECKSALESnMMat64_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, g_NBRLines_REC_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, g1_EVIS NBR_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, h_WKLY_RUNTIME_SHIFT_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, i_TYPEPLANTSHIFTS_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, j_GIBHARVPAY_DEPT_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, k_LiveBirdWght_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH, k1_RangeLBW_FIRSTPROCWOGSMH)
VALUES ('7/5/2016 4:00:43 PM', '12', '15', 'EUFAUL', '3060', '2.2', '13', '290', '-0.06', '8', '290', '725', '6889', '520', '520', '99.26', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '37.8', '-', 'NO', '4.74', '4.4 - 5.2')
```

Comment: Note: The field names are not of my doing

Answer (score 1):

I've found what the issue was. Space found in one of the field names!